# The second call stored procedures causes an error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries in zf2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, stored-procedures, zend-framework2

This is my controller :

```
public function addAction()
{
    if($this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity())
    {
        $this->layout('layout/adminDashboardLayout');
        $request= $this->getRequest();
        if($request->isPost())
        {
            $rowmaterial= new RowmaterialModel();

            //Current User Id from Session
            $session = new Container('user'); 
            $userId = $session->offsetGet('userId');

            $rowmaterial->setCode($request->getPost('category_alias'));
            $rowmaterial->setCategory($request->getPost('category'));
            $rowmaterial->setCreatedOn(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $rowmaterial->setUpdatedOn(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $rowmaterial->setCreatedBy($userId);
            $this->getCategoryTable()->inserts($category);
        }
        $page = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('page', 1);
        $iteratorAdapter = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter(iterator_to_array($this->getRowmaterialTable()->fetchAll()));
        $category = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator($iteratorAdapter); 
        $viewModel= new ViewModel(array(
            'fetchAllDatas' => $category->setCurrentPageNumber($page)->setItemCountPerPage('8'),
            'categories' =>$this->getCategoryTable()->fetchAllCategoryStatusOn(),
            'uom' => $this->getUomTable()->fetchAllUomStatusOn(),
            'flashMessages' => $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages(),
        ));
        return $viewModel;



    }
    else
    {
        $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage("Please Login");
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute("admin");
    }
```

This is my first Model file function :

```
public function fetchAllCategoryStatusOn()
{
    $statement= $this->adapter->query("call fetchAllCategoryStatusOn()");
    $result= $statement->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

This is my second Model file function :

```
public function fetchAllUomStatusOn()
{
    $statement= $this->adapter->query("call fetchAllUomStatusOn()");
    $result= $statement->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

At the time of calling this `fetchAllUomStatusOn()` Storedprocedure this error will show

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries
 are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only
 ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the 
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

This is my global.php file :

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=cp;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
 );
```

I did lot of search I could not get correct answer, at last I get 'closeCursor()' function. I use this function this way ,

```
 public function fetchAllUomStatusOn()
        {
            $statement= $this->adapter->query("call fetchAllUomStatusOn()");
            $statement->closeCursor();
            $result = $statement->execute();
            return $result;
        }
```

By using this function this error will get.

```
   Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement::closeCursor() in /var/www/cp/module/Admin/src/Admin/Model/UomTable.php on line 100.
```

My php version is 5.4. So please help me... This is my first attempt with Stackoverflow. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You're trying to call closeCursor on a [zend pdo statement](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Db.Adapter.Driver.Pdo.Statement.html), not a ["real" pdo statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). Sadly I don't know Zend well enough to offer an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your comment  Joachim Isaksson, but how can i impliment closeCursor with this code...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error. Use `iterator_to_array()` function in controller.

```
public function addAction()
{
   if($this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity())
   {
    $this->layout('layout/adminDashboardLayout');
    $request= $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isPost())
    {
        $rowmaterial= new RowmaterialModel();

        //Current User Id from Session
        $session = new Container('user'); 
        $userId = $session->offsetGet('userId');

        $rowmaterial->setCode($request->getPost('category_alias'));
        $rowmaterial->setCategory($request->getPost('category'));
        $rowmaterial->setCreatedOn(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $rowmaterial->setUpdatedOn(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $rowmaterial->setCreatedBy($userId);
        $this->getCategoryTable()->inserts($category);
    }
    $page = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('page', 1);
    $iteratorAdapter = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter(iterator_to_array($this->getRowmaterialTable()->fetchAll()));
    $category = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator($iteratorAdapter); 
    $viewModel= new ViewModel(array(
            'fetchAllDatas' => $category->setCurrentPageNumber($page)->setItemCountPerPage('8'),
            'categories' =>  iterator_to_array($this->getCategoryTable()->fetchAllCategoryStatusOn()),
            'uom' => iterator_to_array($this->getUomTable()->fetchAllUomStatusOn()),
            'flashMessages' => $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages(),
    ));
    return $viewModel;
}
else
{
    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage("Please Login");
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute("admin");
}
```